# How make logged in members auto logout when visiting a certain URL

Tags: freemember, profile-edit

Maybe strange question, I put it in the setting of this case.
I have build a shoppingsite (Carttrob, Profile:edit) where members are logged in after registration. I also use Freemember to bypass EE messages for the normal login c.q. logout procedure.

Now the owner wants for certain groups a registration without logging in, because he wants to approve them first.
Profile:edit echoes the settings in Membermodule, which is allright, so now I must make an exception here. I could not find an override tag.

My thought is to send the member* to a redirect page where they, without knowing it, become logged out.
*after completion of the form they are at that point logged_in*

I could of course make a button (with some text)to activate the logout procedure, but what if the user does not use that button, and goes back to the site?

My question, how would I code that page? In order to automate the logout procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LogMeIn](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/logmein) add-on has not only option to login user, but also logout. Just add next tag in your template

```
{exp:logmein:logout}
```